# imageNet: ground truth in classification task

Tags: classification, computer-vision

I hope someone working with the www.image-net.org dataset reads this question. I am confused on what the ground truth is for the image classification task and how exactly the predictions of an algorithm are evaluated

1. Is there ONE ground truth label or several for a single image? Reading the description of Task 2 in http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2014/index it sounds like there might be up to `n` many. When looking at this [image](http://karpathy.github.io/assets/ilsvrc2.png) from Karpathy's blog it looks like there is only one (where can I actually see the labels for some example images in the dataset?).
2. If there are more than one ground truth label per image, the algorithm actually has to predict all of them within its allowed five predictions to not make any mistake. This is how it looks to me in the description of Task to, but Karpathy writes:

> The teams have to predict 5 (out of 1000) classes and an image is considered to be correct if at least one of the predictions is the ground truth.

I am confused. Can someone clarify?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm assuming that there is only 1 ground-truth label. The whole idea of allowing 5 prediction is that a picture of a dishwasher might also include things like a counter or a cupboard and kitchen might also be a good label for such a picture. In that case, even with perfect detection power, it might still be ambiguous what the correct label is. So the idea is that you only need to have the that 1 correct label in your top 5. However I couldn't find a definitive answer to confirm this.

Comment: @dim Sounds logical. However, the definition of Task 2 is weird then, isn't it? Also it is weird why one should only annotate one single object in an image, where there might be many of interest.

Comment: Well, for a given image it might not be clear what should and shouldn't be included in its labeling. You can imagine a picture of a single brick might be labelled as such. But should every single pictures with a brick or a brick wall be labelled as such, even if it is only a small part of the background? It might not even be clear what the 'primary' label of a picture should be. I think it is actually quiet elegant to just say: we only label each picture once with a 'primary' label, but allow for 5 guesses to get it right to cape with any ambiguities.

Comment: Yes, it seems like a good solution. Even though one could get many more training examples from the images for the classes if one had assigned several labels. I tend to believe this (one label per image) is how its done, but still do not get the definition of Task 2 then.